# UnicodeEncodeError in IPython but not standard REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, ipython

I'm reading in a file that contains Unicode characters using Python 3.6.3 .  In the standard Python REPL, I'm able to read the file with no problems by specifying UTF-8 encoding:

```
>>> with open("emoji.csv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     lines = f.readlines()
>>> lines
['this line has an emoji \U0001f644\n']
```

No problems there.  However, when I try the same in IPython 6.1.0, I get the following `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
In [1]: with open('emoji.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
...:     lines = f.readlines()
...:

In [2]: lines
Out[2]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3fb162a4fe05> in <module>()
----> 1 lines

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py in __call__(self, result)
    259             self.fill_exec_result(result)
    260             if format_dict:
--> 261                 self.write_format_data(format_dict, md_dict)
    262                 self.log_output(format_dict)
    263             self.finish_displayhook()

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py in write_format_data(self, format_dict, md_dict)
    188                 result_repr = '\n' + result_repr
    189 
--> 190         print(result_repr)
    191 
    192     def update_user_ns(self, result):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f644' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Similarly, if I try to simply encode and decode the Unicode character by itself, I get the same error:

```
In [1]: '\U0001f644'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
Out[1]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f644' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is causing this, and how do I read this file in IPython?

**Edit**: It seems this is a function of IPython using an ASCII encoding by default:

```
In [1]: from IPython.utils.encoding import get_stream_enc; import sys

In [2]: get_stream_enc(sys.stdout)
Out[2]: 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

However, I don't see anything in the IPython documentation on how to change this.  Is this possible?

Comment: It's not reading the file what fails (that would be a **De**codeError), but the representation in the command-line. It seems you need to reconfigure your terminal to handle UTF-8 output.

Comment: That encode/decode sequence you're doing doesn't make sense. It's like writing a document in English and then immediately attempting to read it under the assumption that it's in Japanese.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, that was just a typo - fixed it.

Comment: @lenz If it's a terminal output issue, why do I not get the error in the built-in python REPL?

Comment: IPython has custom display logic. What IPython is trying to print is different from what the regular Python interactive mode prints.

Comment: Yep, as user2357112 said, the REPL is clever enough to resort to using the built-in function `ascii`. IPython tries to do more fancy stuff when displaying, but is apparently less willing to back-off.

Comment: @lenz Thanks, that makes sense. Is this possible to change?

Comment: It depends on the tool (terminal) you use and on the configs. You need to specify this information. Maybe this will eventually be more of a [superuser](https://superuser.com/) question.

Comment: You probably can't change this from within IPython. I don't really know, but I guess IPython already figured out that your terminal only supports ASCII. Try to change the locale and/or terminal settings. Maybe you need to switch to a more capable terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to my system using a POSIX locale.  Setting `$PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` resolved the issue by overriding the ASCII-based encoding IPython was using by default.